# Catching exceptions with objective-c in Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, exception, gcc

I have some sample code that doesn't run the way I think it should.

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
#import <Foundation/NSException.h>
#import <Foundation/NSAutoreleasePool.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  @try {
    NSException *e = [NSException
      exceptionWithName: @"NSException"
                 reason: @"The level is below 0"
               userInfo: nil];
    @throw e;
  } @catch ( NSException *e ) {
    printf( "+%s: ", [[e name] UTF8String] );
  }

  [pool release];
}
```

I run it as following:

```
> gcc -g -c main.m -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I/usr/include/GNUstep
> gcc main.o -lgnustep-base
> ./a.out
```

The result is:

```
Aborted
```

A little bit of playing with the GNU debugger showed me that the catch clause is never reached. It seems to work mac though.

Why do I not get into the catch clause?

Comment: You may need to start `NSApplication` in order to get the Objective-C stuff to run.  *maybe*  My other thought is that `@throw` is throwing *up* the call stack?  Try calling a "normal" Objective-C exception like `[[NSArray array] objectAtIndex:-1]` or something.

Comment: it seems, naturally, that @catch is expected to follow @try, so I cannot place it above @try in the callstack. I tried `@throw [[NSArray array] objectAtIndex:-1]` with `@catch NSArray`, but I got the same result.

Comment: It looks like `@try` won't work outside of a [`NSApplication`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ExceptionHandling)  All the [code I've seen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-BBCHGJIJ) seems to be within the Objective-C portions of the program, and not in main.m (which is almost purely C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers needed can be found in this mail thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss-gnustep@gnu.org/msg11979.html

To get proper objective-c exception handling one might need to compile with the -fobjc-exceptions flag.

```
> gcc -g -c main.m -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fobjc-exceptions -I/usr/include/GNUstep
> gcc main.o -lgnustep-base
> ./a.out
```